# How to calculate and display the result, the number of times executed loop?

Tags: loops, swift

I want to learn how to count and display the result of how many times he worked in the loop Swift. Thanks in advance!

```
    import Foundation

var result: Int
var i: Int = 1

for i = 1; i <= 20; i++  {
    println("The result \(i)")
}
```

I want to do that after this code, the result was derived, for example, how many times a user has guessed this number and how many times lost, so I do not know how to do it.

```
import Foundation

var randomNumber = 1
var userGuess = 1
var continueGuessing = true
var keepPlaying = true
var input = ""

while (keepPlaying) {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101)) //get a random number between 0-100
    println("The random number to guess is: \(randomNumber)"  );
    while (continueGuessing) {
        println ("Pick a number between 0 and 100. ")
        input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! //get keyboard input
        input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil) //strip off the /n
        userGuess = input.toInt()!
        if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
            continueGuessing = false
            println("Correct number!");
        }
            //nested if statement
        else if (userGuess > randomNumber){
            //user guessed too high
            println("Your guess is too high");
        }
        else{
            // no reason to check if userGuess < randomNumber. It has to be.
            println("Your guess is too low");
        }
    }
    println ("Play Again? Y or N");
    input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

    if (input == "N" || input == "n"){
        keepPlaying = false
    }
    continueGuessing = true
}
```

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. Your loop will print values, what more are you looking for? What did you try and what did it do wrong?

Comment: I want to do that after this code, the result was derived, for example, how many times a user has guessed this number and how many times lost, so I do not know how to do it. You look at bottom please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize a variable outside the `while (continueGuessing)` loop.

Inside the loop, increment that variable.

This will count how many guesses the person had.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (answers in BOLD) Remember to write '**count = 0**' at the end, otherwise it will keep incrementing after the user presses 'y' to start again.

```
//  Marty Tripp - Updated to count Guesses
//  main.swift
//  Guess


import Foundation

var randomNumber = 1
var userGuess:Int? = 1
var continueGuessing = true
var keepPlaying = true
var input = ""
**var count = 0**

while (keepPlaying) {
randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101))  //get a random number      between 0-100
//print("The random number to guess is: \(randomNumber)"  );
while  (continueGuessing) {
    print ("Pick a number between 0 and 100. ")
    input = NSString(data:     NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String //get keyboard input
    input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)  //strip off the /n
        userGuess = Int(input)
        **count += 1**
    if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
        continueGuessing = false
        print("Correct Number!");
        print("Your number of tries were:", count)
    }


    //nested if statement
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
        //user guessed too high
        print("Sorry cutie pie, your guess is too high");
    }
    else{
        //no reason to check if userGuess < randomNumber.  It has to be.
        print("Sorry cutie pie, your guess is too low");
    }
}
print("Play Again? Y or N");
input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData,     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString:     "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
**count = 0**
if (input == "N" || input == "n"){
    keepPlaying = false
}
continueGuessing = true
}
```